# Visual C++ DLL that checks if file exists

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

I made this dll file that tries to check if a file exists. But even if I manually create the file, my dll still can't find it.

My dll retrieves the process id of the running program and looks for a file that is named after the pid.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing :(

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int clientpid = GetCurrentProcessId();
ifstream clientfile;
string clientpids, clientfilepath;

VOID LoadDLL() {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    std::cout << "Debug Start" << std::endl;

    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << clientpid;
    clientpids = ostr.str();
    ostr.str("");

    TCHAR tempcvar[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemDirectory(tempcvar, MAX_PATH);
    ostr << tempcvar << "\\" << clientpids << ".nfo" << std::endl;
    clientfilepath = ostr.str();
    //clientfile.c_str()
    ostr.str("");

    std::cout << "Start search for: " << clientfilepath << std::endl;

    FOREVER {
        clientfile.open(clientfilepath,ios::in);
        if(clientfile.good()) {
            std::cout << "Exists!" << std::endl;
        }

        Sleep(10);
    };
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?
Can you describe exactly what happens, and how that is different from what you expect? 
Does it work if you use it within a regular program, rather than as a DLL?

Comment: Just because you can't open a file, it doesn't mean the file doesn't exist.  Use `GetFileAttributes(szFile) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` to test for existence.

Comment: Ok I tried changing the forever loop a bit and got a ERROR_INVALID_NAME error. Was my converting the filepath from string to LPCTSTR wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Supposing you are working with UNICODE**
I think the problems goes in the following line: 
`ostr << tempcvar << "\\" << clientpids << ".nfo" << std::endl;`
 The tempcvar is a tchar, and maybe you are working with unicode, so it means tempcvar is a widechar.
The result that you get inserting `tempcvar` in `ostr` is not what you are expecting (You are mixing multibyte with widechar too). A solution to this problem is converting `tempcvar` into a multi byte string (`const char*` or `char*`...)

Look at this example based on your code (Look at the convertion between tchar to multibyte char)

```
VOID LoadDLL() {

AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
std::cout << "Debug Start" << std::endl;
std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << clientpid;
clientpids = ostr.str();
ostr.str("");

TCHAR tempcvar[MAX_PATH];
GetSystemDirectory(tempcvar, MAX_PATH);

// Convertion between tchar in unicode (wide char) and multibyte
wchar_t * tempcvar_widechar = (wchar_t*)tempcvar;
char* to_convert;
int bytes_to_store = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,
    0,
    tempcvar_widechar,
    -1,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
to_convert = new char[bytes_to_store];

WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,
    0,
    tempcvar_widechar,
    -1,to_convert,bytes_to_store,NULL,NULL);

// Using char* to_convert that is the tempcvar converted to multibyte
ostr << to_convert << "\\" << clientpids << ".nfo" << std::endl;
clientfilepath = ostr.str();
//clientfile.c_str()
ostr.str("");

std::cout << "Start search for: " << clientfilepath << std::endl;

FOREVER {
    clientfile.open(clientfilepath,ios::in);
    if(clientfile.good()) {
        std::cout << "Exists!" << std::endl;
    }

    Sleep(10);
};

}
```

You can search more about the wide string to multibyte string convertion if this example does not works to you.
Check if you are working with Unicode, if you are, maybe this is your problem.
If you are not working with unicode, the problem in your code can be opening the file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I set the properties to work on multi-byte upon starting the project :(

Comment: Yeah I double checked it. I'm really lost as to why he can't find it :( Anyway, I'm gonna try switching to unicode and try your advice as it's better than having no solution at all.

Comment: Just a quick answer in a commnet... You inserted a break line in the `ostr` next to the `GetSystemDirectory`, look: `ostr << tempcvar << "\\" << clientpids << ".nfo" << std::endl` std::endl means breakline, I think that's the reason about your problem

Comment: THAT'S IT! THAT'S WHAT WAS WRONG! LOL hahaha god that mistake is so basic I didn't bother double checking :O

That mistake came out because I was just copypasting my cout lines out of laziness. Thanks @Spamdark

Comment: It was like hidden from the people (All the people that answered your question didn't notice it...). I think that's a big fail, anyway, your welcome :)!